# How to name all data except for header row in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

Suppose I have some data like this:

```
Name    Number
alan    1
bobby   2
cory    3
david   4
```

Assume that "Name" is in cell A1. I'd like to be able to name this range but not include the header row. I know that I can refer to the data as `$A$2:$B$5`, but I'd like to not have to have any knowledge about how many rows are in the table, and I definitely don't want to have to highlight the cells with a mouse. Is there any way to do this? And if the best way is to use `$A$2:$B$5`, is there any way to find out how many rows I'm dealing with besides scrolling all the way to the end?

From the comments and answers, it looks like the way that most people select data is by using the mouse or keyboard shortcut to select lots of rows and columns. This still bothers me because I'm always having to scroll all the way to the top of the sheet again. Is there any way to avoid having to scroll through the data so much?

Comment: <END> followed by <SHIFT><DOWN> will take you to the last row with data, highlighting all the cells, and then <END> followed by <SHIFT><RIGHT> will take you to the last column with data, highlighting all the cells.

Comment: Search for "dynamic named range" there are plenty of resources on the Internet already.

Comment: E.g. here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/830287

Comment: @RonMaupin Thanks for the keyboard shortcut. I'm on a laptop with no End key, but I was able to figure it out. I've edited my post to ask an additional question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this still falls in the category of keyboard shortcuts, but I find using `<Ctrl>+(Directional arrow)` to be the fastest way to navigate in Excel. This can be combined with `<Shift>` to select ranges. Assigning names is per usual (I like `<Alt>,<M>,<M>,<D>`).

So, in your example, start in A2, then `<Ctrl>+<Shift>+<Down>` and `<Ctrl>+<Shift>+<Right>`. To return to the top, just release `<Shift>` and press `<Ctrl>+<Up>`, `<Ctrl>+<Left>`. If you're doing this while entering a formula, you can hit F4 to lock the range (i.e. add $ to the range reference).

Caveat: This method will only take you to the next empty cell, so if you have empty cells in your table, it may not take you to the "end." I still find it an extremely useful method.

Comment: This is what I use all the time now. I find it acceptable because I'm not spending all day scrolling even though it's still very much 'touching' all of the data.

Answer (score 0):

Highlight the table, or cells that you desire to be referred to. Then in the upper-left corner where it reads "A2", type over the reference and name it. Now when you reference your table, "A2:B5", you now reference it as "names"; or whatever name you decide to name it.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just make a table out of it and use that.  Learn how to use Tables (in VBA they are called ListObjects) and they make magic happen.

Select A1 --> B5, go to Insert --> Table.  In the new window check "Tabel has headers" and press "OK".  Now in the "Table Tools" --> "Design"-tab, you can modify the appearance, and, most importantly, the name of your table.

Then have a good read through [this](http://www.jkp-ads.com/Articles/Excel2007Tables.asp) document and you are set!